# Problemas con script bash en CentOS - Lectura de variables

Tags: bash, script, centos, grep

Tengo que hacer un script escrito en bash para hacer auditorías de accesos en mySQL.
Tengo ya las sentencias que he de usar, pero no se como escribir correctamente el script para poder recoger variables y añadirlas a un menú sencillo para hacer mas agradable la experiencia de usuario: me dan un puñado de errores de sintaxis, mal planteamientos o algo ¯_(ツ)_/¯
Adjunto los dos scripts que me dan problemas y sus errores:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
https://pastebin.com/VtyStgjc <- link al código
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
https://pastebin.com/a0Bygj55 <- link al código

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Agradezco cualquier clase de ayuda, gracias!

Comment: por favor incluye el texto del código, con las imágenes no podemos trabajar bien

Comment: Actualizados: he puesto un pastebin con los códigos. Gracias!

Comment: no no, ponlo aquí mismo :) Las preguntas deben ser autocontenidas, sin necesidad de ir a otros sitios para leerlas. Lee [ask]

Answer (score 2):

Que error tan "divertido" el del **primer código**, ya me ha pasado y me ha molestado por días. Estoy seguro que es por los saltos de línea.

Ve qué tipo de saltos de línea tiene configurado ese archivo en sublime en "View" > "Line endings". Ahí te dice si es Unix o Windows para Mac. Puedes seleccionar ahí el tipo Unix pero, en caso de que te llegue a ocurrir de nuevo y no tengas un editor cómodo, puedes utilizar un programa llamado `dos2unix` con algo de tipo:

```
$ dos2unix <tu archivo>
```

O puedes hacer algo similar con `sed` o `tr`:

```
$ sed -i 's/\r//g' <tu archivo>
```

o

```
$ tr -d '\r' < <tu archivo> > archivo_nuevo
```

La explicación es que para cada grupo de sistemas operativos se establecieron convenciones para caracteres de control. En el caso del salto de línea, Windows sigue la convención de utilizar la secuencia de escape `\r\n` y los de la familia Linux utilizan la `\n`, entonces esos caracteres no se ven a simple vista en pantalla y causan estragos.

Puedes ver más información aquí:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Lo que hace `sed` y `tr` en las sugerencias que puse es eliminar el *CR* (Carriage Return) osea el `\r`.

En cambio `dos2unix`, además de hacer esto, puede convertir la codificación de DOS a Unix o de Windows unicode a Unix unicode.

#### ¿Qué hacer si me encuentro con problemas así de extraños?

Pues si ya medio tienes la intuición y estás seguro de que la parte de tu código que quieres depurar está bien, utiliza `cat` con el flag `-A` a ese archivo, esto te permitirá ver caracteres no imprimibles usando las notaciones "^" y "M-", para ver saltos de línea, tabulaciones, etc.

Por ejemplo:

```
$ cat -A archivo_raro
```

Lo que sea `^I` son tabs, lo que sea `^M` son *carriage return's* "\r" y lo que sea `$` es el *line feed* (o *new line*) "\n". Ahora, Si te fijas bien en el error, dice algo como "... no es un identificador válidoea ..." Pareciese ser que se recorre el cursor, puesto que parece que trunca un "valido( en lín)ea" y luego se sobre escriben cosas... pues justamente eso hace el *carriage return*, ahí puedes "sentir" uno de sus efectos.

En el segundo código, parece que que el problema es semejante al primero, en torno a los saltos de línea tipo "DOS". Pero en tu código veo anomalías como que no pones el token `then` después del `if` y tampoco pones un token que indique una evaluación como los son `[, test, [[, ((`, pones de inmediato "$ano", es decir, va a tomar como token a evaluar lo que ingresaste y es muy probable que no significa algo para para bash. Además que después, si de pura casualidad significa algo, por ejemplo, que introduzcas un "ls", el token `!=` por si mismo no significa nada para bash. Precisamente por eso necesita que esté dentro de un evaluador, para que el evaluador entienda tokens como "==", "!=", "&&", "||".

La versión correcta sería algo del estilo:

(**estó está mal, ver la actualización más abajo**)

```
if [[ $ano != [1-9999] ]]; then
```

Pongo el *built-in* `[[` en lugar del `[` porque de lo contrario el evaluador no podría entender la expresión de rango "[1-9999]" y siempre devolvería falso a menos que ingreses la cadena a secas "[1-9999]". Es decir, los *tokens* "!=" y "==" dentro de `[]` comparan cadenas, pero dentro de `[[]]` comparan el valor de la izquierda con un patrón, de la lista de coincidencia de patrones, de la derecha.

Para más información de esto puedes leer en https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs y en https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching

Resumiendo. Elimina los caracteres "\r" o cambia los saltos de línea de Windows a Unix, cambia tus premisas `if a != b` usando el token apropiado, en este caso `[[`, además de utilizar el token `; then` o quitando el ";" por un salto de línea.

(**estó está mal, ver la actualización más abajo**)

```
if [[ $ano != [1-9999] ]]; then
```

Como sugerencia, en tu primer código, no es necesario que utilices las comillas invertidas `` `expresión` `` puesto que de esta manera se corre un proceso en una subshell, lo cual no es necesario pero igual funciona, puedes quitarle esas comillas.

## Actualización 1

@nxnev planteó un punto muy importante, la forma de comparar que "avalé" es errónea debido a una mala interpretación de mi parte al manual.

Es decir, la forma `[[ $numero == [1-9] ]]` compara caracteres individuales entre un rango, el problema que mostró es que, en un ejemplo como:

```
[[ 10 == [1-9999] ]]
```

la evaluación sería falsa.

@nxnev además sugiere una evaluación de la forma

```
(( ano >= 1 && ano <= 9999 ))
```

o utilizar la herramienta `date` para trabajar con fechas.

Otra propuesta que se me ocurrió, que es un tanto engorrosa pero muestra otra utilidad, es usar una expresión regular.

```
[[ $ano =~ ^([1-9]|[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{3}|[0-9]{4})$ ]]
```

Comment: ¡Buena respuesta! Aunque hay un pequeño error. `[1-9999]` no significa "cualquier número entero entre 1 y 9999" sino "cualquier carácter individual entre 1 y 9 en la configuración regional actual". Por ejemplo, la expresión `[[ 10 == [1-9999] ]]` da la impresión de ser verdadera pero en realidad es falsa: `if [[ 10 == [1-9999] ]]; then echo Verdadero; else echo Falso; fi`. Una posible solución sería `(( ano >= 1 && ano <= 9999 ))` pero yo me decanto por usar `date` para parsear fechas.

Comment: Corregido, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

En cuanto al código no le veo problemas (al menos el primero que has puesto, solo miré ese). Creo que es un problema del shell que utilizas. De todos modos, en el script indicas que se debe ejecutar con bash `#!/bin/bash` y despues invocas el script con Shell Bourne (sh). Prueba a ejecutar lo siguiente:

```
/bin/bash
/media/sf_compartida/uno.sh
```